# Is the RAM for a lambda function for one invocation or all concurrent invocations?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

As I understand it, AWS Kinesis data stream may have multiple shards. Each shard will invoke one lambda function, and they can happen in parallel.

And so the question is, the RAM that you configure for the lambda function, is it one function or for all functions running concurrently?

For example, if I configure 1GB for my lambda function and 10 lambda functions are invoked concurrently, will the total RAM for all functions be 1GB or 10GB?

Comment: A lambda function runs inside an execution environment (micro VM). At a time, an execution environment can only run 1 lambda, so it will have access to whole memory. Once first execution finishes, another request enters the execution environment. If 100 requests come simultaneously, then 100 execution environment will be created by Lambda service.

Comment: And each of those 100 execution environments will have the configured RAM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RAM is allocated per running instance. Each instance can handle one invocation at a time.

To your question. In total 10GB are allocated each 1GB per instance. Concurrent invocations do not share memory